# Non Required JSON attribute in Spring (Jackson Mapping)

Tags: json, spring, controller, jackson

I have this function in a Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/*", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@Consumes("application/json")
public JSONresponse alta(@RequestBody JSONrequest parametros, HttpServletRequest request) {
   some code...}
```

JSON request is a JavaClass like this:

```
public class JSONrequest {
      private String code;
      private String message;
      //getters and setter}
```

I'm using Jackson to map this, and works correctly. But my question is: It's possible make message attribute  non required? I would like the web service to accept JSON with both attributes or only with the "code" attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [required](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html#required%28%29) property of JsonProperty. But this property is available from 2.7.x or higher versions.

```
public class JSONrequest {

      @JsonProperty(value ="CODE",required = true)
      private String code;

      @JsonProperty(value ="MESSAGE",required = false)
      private String message;
```

Above example makes code attribute as mandatory while message as an optional field for deserialization.